# What are the advantages of pgSQL+PostGIS+pgRouting over a simple MySQL+handwritten routing algorithms?

Tags: postgis, openstreetmap, pgrouting

**Goal:**

To have a routable set of roads in a database and to have a software that can calculate the shortest path (e.g. simple Dijkstra) through this set in a reasonable amount of time (up to 2 seconds). Required to be usable in the real world by real vehicles.

**Problem:**

I have written a few parsers to parse .osm nodes and edges into a MySQL database. Then I applied a Java application that loads all the nodes and edges into memory, creates a graph from those and does a Dijkstra's algorithm routing on it. I am satisfied with the speed that it has.

Recently I found out that Openstreetmap project has switched from MySQL to PostgreSQL.

Then I found the pgRouting project.

http://www.slideshare.net/antonpa/shortest-path-search-for-real-road-networks-and-dynamic-costs-with-pgrouting-1097533

I was impressed by the possible advantages:

- it can take traffic lights into account;
- it can take crossings into account;
- it can take signs and restrictions into account;
- it even can take slopes into account!
- it can take turn restrictions into account;
- it even promises to take weather conditions into account.

**So the questions are:**

1. Are all those advantages real?
2. Isn't pgRouting a kind of a blackbox? There are just a few tutorials on how to use it, and even these tutorials introduce even more unanswered questions. Isn't it simpler to build the desired [Goal] system from scratch?
3. What's the whole purpose of storing routable data the PostgreSQL/PostGIS way (geometry columns, strange database schema) instead of having just two tables - nodes and edges in a simple MySQL database?

Comment: 1.yes, 2. pgRouting is documented, 3. turn-by-turn, bi-direction, resistances.

Answer (score 16):

> Are all those advantages real?

It can actually do those things, if that's what you mean. It takes work from you to set the data up properly.

> Isn't pgRouting a kind of a blackbox? There are just a few
>   tutorials on how to use it, and even
>   these tutorials introduce even more
>   unanswered questions. Isn't it simpler
>   to build the desired [Goal] system
>   from scratch?

The documentation isn't good, that's true.  But, all of the source is there. It's hardly a black box and can keep things [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself).

> What's the whole purpose of storing routable data the
>   PostgreSQL/PostGIS way (geometry
>   columns, strange database schema)
>   instead of having just two tables -
>   nodes and edges in a simple MySQL
>   database?

If MySQL does everything  you need and you're familiar with it then use that. PostgreSQL/PostGIS is much more powerful from a relational database and spatial analysis perspective. That doesn't mean you have to use it or even that it's better *for your application*. If you want better performance, more features and strong spatial analysis functions, switch to PostgreSQL/PostGIS. If what you have works well enough, don't worry about it.

See also:  [Cross Compare of SQL Server, MySQL, and PostgreSQL](http://www.bostongis.com/PrinterFriendly.aspx?content_name=sqlserver2008_postgis_mysql_compare)